# texmaker does not compile if pdf already exists

Tags: texlive, texmaker

Probably a simple thing, but I'm a bit lost. I use texmaker with texlive, Windows. Today I changed something in the configuration in order to set up TEXMFHOME, so now I can compile with my own class, everything is OK, except:

when I run pdflatex from texmaker, it compiles only if there is no pdf for that file. So, if it's a new file, I can compile it, and, I can also run successfully pdflatex from the console. How can I solve this?

Comment: then you need to explain **exactly** what you changed in relation to TEXMFHOME as you can easily make bad mistakes when you mess with those.

Comment: What is the error message? Did you have the pdf file open in any program (a viewer?) when you tried compiling?